# Passing arguments when python subprocess.Popen in running

Tags: python, python-2.7, subprocess

I have simple Application (*.exe) to which I am passing command line arguments using Python `subprocess.Popen` as shown below:

```
Write_data = Popen(["Test.exe", arg1, arg2)], 
                    cwd = TARGET_PATH,
                    shell = True,
                    stdin=PIPE, 
                    stdout=PIPE)
output = ''
for line in iter(Write_data.stdout.readline, ""):
    print line,
    output += line
```

I have programmed my application to receive the arguments and do certain operations. Currently I am calling the subprocess function multiple times every time I want to test my application with different data.

Is it possible to run the subprocess only once and send arguments to a running process?

I tried `Write_Data.stdin.write(arg3, arg4)`, but it doesn't seem to work.

Comment: Don't use the code snippet function unless using html/css/javascript.

Comment: There is a mistake in code `(["Test.exe", arg1, arg2)],` should be `(["Test.exe", arg1, arg2],`

Comment: I think that what you are doing is the only way, it's not possible to send new arguments to an already running program.

Answer (score 0):

I think arguments are no tool for inter-process communication.

You can interact with a running program using stdin and stdout as you tried but you can only write to stdin like you would write into a file 
and read from stdout. There is no parameters in stdin.

What happens when you write to stdin depends on the receiver.
But you can call your receiver on the command line and see what happens if you pipe something into the stdin.